# Using bitwise operators ~ and & to make | Operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've got to solve a task but can't find the answer: 
Compute `x | y` using only `~` and `&` 
The maximum allowed operations are 8

Edit:
In twos complement and 32-bit representations of integers.
Right shifts are performed arithmetically.

Comment: Draw some truth tables. Also, this isn't really a programming question. It's more of a logic question using bit-wise operator syntax.

Comment: If you have NOT and AND available you can use [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic) logic to get to any operator

Comment: @msam: Thanks that was the right food for my thoughts :)

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the truth table of `x | y` you will see:

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

`x | y` will be 1 if both`x` and `y` are not `0`. You can translate it to `~(~x & ~y)`:

```
~(~0 & ~0) = ~(1 & 1) = ~1 = 0
~(~0 & ~1) = ~(1 & 0) = ~0 = 1
~(~1 & ~0) = ~(0 & 1) = ~0 = 1
~(~1 & ~1) = ~(0 & 0) = ~0 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered, but they made no reference to De Morgan.

De Morgan's Law says that ~(~A & ~B) is equivalent to (A | B). My professor in Logic Design told us to "move bubble, change symbol" where a NOT (~) is a "bubble" and AND/OR are "symbols".

(A' & B')' -> move/distribute the "bubbles" -> (A & B) -> change the "symbol" -> (A | B).

This also works backwards, where the lack of a NOT can be treated as no bubble at all.

(A | B) -> add "bubbles" -> (A' | B')' -> change the symbol -> (A' & B')'

[See De Morgan's Laws for some more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).